# How can I Differentiate between OnClick and Swipe on a Firemonkey TListView Item with Delphi XE6

Tags: android, mobile, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I have a form with a TListView on it.  I load up some items, and it displays fine.
If I tap (OnClick) an item, I can display a second form with the item details, and some additional options.

However, if I swipe right (to activate the "Delete" button), I get the OnClick event, and the detail form displays.  When I close the Detail form (or use the "Back" button), the TListView now has the Delete button displayed.

So, the short version of this is how can I stop the OnClick event from firing when a Swipe is done?

I've tried adding a flag, and setting the flag in the OnDeleteChangeVisible, and/or OnGesture, but the flag never seems to get set, and I don't see these events firing when I run in debug mode.

```
var isDelete: Boolean

procedure TfrmTaskList.lvTaskListDeleteChangeVisible(Sender: TObject;
  AValue: Boolean);
begin
  if (AValue = True) then
    isDelete := True
  else
    isDelete := False;
end;

procedure TfrmTaskList.lvTaskListGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
    if (EventInfo.GestureID = sgiRight) then
    begin
      isDelete := True
    end
    else
    begin
      isDelete := False;
    end;
end;
```

Any help, advice, resources would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Slightly different question, but ultimately the same issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681940/scrolling-vs-selecting-delphi-xe6

Comment: Thank you @ThisGuy for the response.  It is similar (and I may implement that solution as a stopgap), but I think the time differential between a tap and a swipe is pretty short, and would be difficult to calculate reliably.  Also, long tap will fire before mouse up if you hold long enough.  I'm not in need of long tap right now, but it would be great to find a more reliable solution in order to take advantage of all of the available gestures, instead of just two.

Answer (score 4):

Use `OnTap` instead of `OnClick` event